# Passing arguments to redis-cli

Tags: redis, lua

I have a simple LUA script that looks like:

```
local msg = "Hello, world! " .. tostring(ARGV[1])
return msg
```

I am on Windows and I call this script with
redis-cli --eval hello.lua 0, "USA"

But I always get "Hello, world! nil"

How should I pass an argument to this test script?

Comment: If the Windows port is like the official branch, you'll need a space **before and after** the comma, i.e. `redis-cli --eval hello.lua , USA` (note that you do not need to specify the number of keys as everything before the comma is considered as such)

Comment: @ItamarHaber, make it the answer ;)

Comment: Only if the behavior is the same - I never tried the Windows fork

Comment: Works!! Thank you

Comment: @KevinBurton cool - made it into an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the Windows port is like the official branch, you'll need a space before and after the comma, i.e.:

```
redis-cli --eval hello.lua , USA
```

(note that you do not need to specify the number of keys as everything before the comma is considered as such)